# What are the hidden configurations that enable TLS communication with only CA info from Kafka cluster?

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I have this code, it works with my Kafka cluster (I got it from my colleague and no idea how it is configured). I copied the content of cluster-ca-cert file into the file myca.ca.pem. My issue here is that I don't get why it works without many parameters necessary to establish an SSL connection.

```
from time import sleep
from json import dumps
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer( bootstrap_servers='test-kafka.com:443',value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8'), security_protocol='SSL', ssl_cafile = 'myca.ca.pem', ssl_check_hostname=False)
for e in range(1000):
    data = {'number' : e}
    producer.send('hello', value=data)
    sleep(5)
```

I understand what and how pub/priv key or CA are used for, but when putting all these things in SSL and Kafka context, I have difficulties understanding. Many questions come up in my mind, e.g.

- Where are pub/priv keys generated by the client? In the code, I don't expose either pub key or CA anywhere, how the server can trust the client?
- Why does it work with only CA from the cluster, how about pub key generated at the servers side? Same, in the code, I only copy the CA from the server, not the public key.
- Does it mean there is a configuration that allows using a default value from somewhere? I am sure there is, just want to know which part of the SSL handshake is configured.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: _Where are pub/priv keys from the client_ - That's your pem file. How do you know the CA wasn't used to generate that cert?

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer for your question. You are right, I am not sure what I know, that's why I asked the question :) Anyway, just to be clear, I mean where the pub/priv keys of the clients. The CA in my pem file is from the Kafka cluster (which is SSL server I believe).

Comment: What do you mean by "where"? The pem file is on the clients filesystem, not the server

Comment: While you can use the cluster certs for clients (these are certs used between brokers for replication), you should instead generate unique certs per client application

Comment: Probably my question is not quite clear. Let me try this way, hopefully, we can understand each other better. For the client and server to talk via SSH, the client must know the public key of the server, and the server should know the public key of the client. In my source code, probably the client knows the public key of the server via the PEM file (which is copied from the server) but why is there no code of the client that generates a public key to send back to the user? I think that is basically my main concern.

Comment: I assume you mean TLS/SSL, not SSH. And the server would be secured via JKS files and the CA on the server truststore authorizes the keys. Client doesn't need extra code that's handled by the Kafka protocol and SSL handshake https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html